# Al-Bayt Al-Mamur location

Tags: hadith

The question is about Al-Bayt Al-Mamur's location. Some people say that Al-Bayt Al-Mamur is right above the Kaaba. What hadith is this opinion based on? How authentic is this?

Answer (score 0):

It's located in the same position of the kaba but it's obviously in the skies and everyday 7000 angels do dawaf and they won't come back in the next day another 700 will come and do dawaf subhanalah

Comment: What hadith is it based on?

Comment: I mean the opinion that it is exactly above the Kaaba on the earth